# Composer: Require a package with custom namespace

Tags: php, composer-php, alias

I've been progressively starting to use Composer on my PHP projects, however there's something that I always questioned.

For instance, let's say this is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ramsey/uuid": "~2.8"
    }
}
```

I'm telling composer I want the package `ramsey/uuid` and as expected it download and includes the package.

When I want to access the classes on the package, I'm forced to something like:

```
$uuid = \Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4();
```

Is there a way I can require the package and force a simpler namespace like for eg. `\Uuid::uuid4();`, avoiding the need to write the full NS including package author?

What should I change on my `composer.json` to be able to do this? Thank you.

**Note**: I'm aware of PHP's `use`. I could `use Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid;`... However I need to do this in every single file, it's not practical. Even less if I'm putting together a small self-usage framework. I want for instante to have `\Util\UUID`mapped to `\Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid`.

I also think the file `autoload_psr4.php` could be changed to accomplish this, however after an `update` all changes are discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing you can do to shorten these namespaces.

Composer doesn't have to do anything with PHP namespaces. The name you use to identify the software package is unrelated to the PHP namespace. They don't have to match in any way. Composer only provides an autoloader that will include the source code of a class you are using in your code. The possible alteratives would be to either load that source code manually using `include_once()` or `require_once()`, or create an autoloader on your own that does this.

Now that Composer is out of the way, we can discuss namespaces and class names. Before PHP 5.3, there were no namespaces. Classes either were not generally used in multiple projects because they were created with short names that likely would conflict with other classes bearing the same name, or they were extended to contain a distinguishing component in their name, like `Zend_Controller_Abstract` or `sfController` (from Symfony 1).

These class names also tend to get very long, especially with the invention of PSR-0 autoloading (which was for a very long time the only PSR standard ever defined).

With namespaces you get at least a method to shorten those class name references in your code.

You have to either use the original, long form in every place you use, or you have to import it with a shorter alias. Yes, you have to repeat the import clause in every file - but you don't import EVERY class into EVERY file, you would only import the classes you actually use.

Using an IDE is very helpful with these tasks. They offer you a way to search in all available classes for the one you want to use but can't remember. They also deal with importing namespaced classes into your file. You'd rarely ever need to manually "add the imports everywhere".